# Communication between ElasticSearch and Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am trying to understand how Kibana communicates with ElasticSearch. Does this communication happen b/w the browser and the ElasticSearch server directly (Bypassing the Kibana server) or all Kibana requests go through Kibana server which then pass them on to ElasticSearch.

I am trying to figure out how to implement security around my ElasticSearch & Kibana based servers.

Comment: Second variant. You can open 9200 port (usually it is Elasticsearch port) only for Kibana and Kibana will work fine. So you don't need direct access to ES.

Answer (score 2):

In Kibana3, the browser would talk to elasticsearch directly.  Any protection of elasticsearch had to be done via a front-end web server, typically nginx with a bunch of proxy rules to prevent certain actions, etc.

In Kibana4, they realized that having a server would be beneficial, so your browser talks to the kibana server, which talks to elasticsearch.

The "official" way to protect elasticsearch is with "[shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield)", which handles authentication and authorization for actions against the server.

Comment: But should perhaps note that shield is a costed option. The alternative is to reverse proxy between kibana and elasticsearch, but that's quite hard work to implement

Answer (score 0):

in kibana 5 a request is sent from a web browser to kibana backend(developped using hapi js) then this request will be sent to elasticsearch using elasticsearch plugin wich is one of the kibana core plugins.